# Как узнать уникалный ID ПК не зависимо какая система?

Tags: python

Создаю регистрацию пользователя. Необходимо записывать его в БД из которой будет браться информация относительно его ID для того чтобы делать сразу переход на нужную страницу с его данными. Вот я и подумал что нужно брать либо его IP но это переменная и не очень правильная штука, либо ID его ПК. Возможно есть и другие варианты и моя логика не верная.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145044/discussion-on-question-by------id---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Ilnarildarovuch правильный ответ дал. `uuid.getnode() ` - это мак адрес первой сетевухии. Остальное всё не кроссплатформенное. Подделать можно что угодно..

Comment: @Ilnarildarovuch, открою тайну, MAC - это тоже переменная. Причем меняется на раз-два.